# Your device isn´t compatible with this version

Tags: android, google-play

I develop an application and its in Alpha Testings stage in play store. I use a couple devices to test it up.
Yesterday I encountered a weird problem after app update. In play store page I get "Your device isn't compatible with this version" message for one of my devices, so can't install an app there. But it works just fine during development, for debug build!
Country settings of play store is not a problem since I allow all countries for testing now.
Update: I was able to install signed apk to the device. The problem is not in a file or code, but in Play Store settings! What else could it be except Country settings?
Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your build.gradle file has the a `minSdkVersion` that is lower or equal to your device?

Comment: Check if the app is available in your country, for your device version inside playstore app configurations, it may helps.

Comment: minSdkVersion and country settings are ok!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same problem as you. On tablets our application could not be downloaded or even found through search on the Google Play Store. The reason this is happening is because Google Play filters applications based on your device's hardware and software capabilities.

My app had specified `CALL_PHONE` as one of the required permissions, but in code we handled tablets by checking whether the device had phone capabilities. However, since the permission was declared in the `AndroidManifest` file, Google Play assumed that only devices with calling capabilities could download and use the application.

The fix was to explicitly tell Google that phone calling is not a required feature:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false"/>
```

The [`uses-feature`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) segment in the developer guides contains all the relevant information:

> Google Play uses the  elements declared in your app
>   manifest to filter your app from devices that do not meet its hardware
>   and software feature requirements.
>
> By specifying the features that your application requires, you enable
>   Google Play to present your application only to users whose devices
>   meet the application's feature requirements, rather than presenting it
>   to all users.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your problem is linked to the fact that your "google play services" is not up to date or even installed.

Try check it out [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but google play services are ok